# Changing colors of invitation online, variable colors

Tags: html, css, variables, user-interface

I wanna try to build my own invitation builder for my dad's work.

We have a very simple invitation that I can recreate in css but I would like to let people  choose there own colors and text directly on the website.

The invitation has some circles and text on the circles. So basically I would like to allow people to change the colors of the circle and the background. I was searching on the internet and found Sass but i don't know for sure if this is what i need.

Can someone help to find information on how to achieve this.

Comment: Maybe give us some link to this invitation website or jsfiddle. Besides And if I understand correctly you can use jQuery to change background-color and plugin jquery color plugin for colors.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com/%E2%80%8E). In case you're not familiar with JQuery, it is a Javascript library that has many pre-built functions, and in addition, people are always extending and improving upon it. For instance I did the quick Google search on "JQuery color picker" and came up with a number of results. For instance [this one here](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/#about).